# JSON array managing

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I am studying angular js and I think its a simple question

See script - Its repeating tag ( ng-repeat )

```
<a href="#/modelList/{{carBrandList.data[5].model}}">{{brand.model}} </a>
```

You note this `{{carBrandList.data[5].model}}` In that tags

**my Question**

I want to be set array value correspond repeating row -  {{carBrandList.data[`dynamic correspond value`].model}}

**my failure code**

```
<a href="#/modelList/{{carBrandList.data[`{{$index + 1}}`].model}}">{{brand.model}} </a>
```

> controller

```
angular.module('carPricesApp.controllers',[]).
controller('carPricesController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.carBrandList = [];
    $http.get("apidata.js")
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.carBrandList = response
      }) 
})
```

Comment: use ng-href https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref
you also dont need quotes around that {{$index + 1}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in ng-repeat

```
<a href="#/modelList/{{carBrandList.data[$index + 1].model}}">{{brand.model}} </a>
```

Comment: your welcome buddy.. yeah its easy to learn :) start with a small project..  Try this  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Thanks :) May i ask your skype id